# Is it okay to use models from one Django app in another?

Tags: python, django, django-models

folks.

I have a simple Django project.
There's an app that receives data, processes it, and stores it in a DB.
Of course, I'd like to show this data. To me, it looks more like a separate Django app.
But then comes the question: What should I do with models? It looks really stupid to copy it but at the same time, it's kinda wrong to use models from one app in another.

Comment: You can use models from another app. However usually if you render data, that simply belongs to the same app where you fetch that data, update that data, remove that data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not separate the display of one app's models into another app; keep it in the same app. Use views and templates in the same Django app to display the data.

If you need to display it in a really special way (intense graphing, etc) then find a display app and reference the display app in your current app.